# Create different combinations of images, based on percentage

Tags: algorithm, image-processing, calculus

If I have 3 different images and A, B and C matrices, represent the intensity distribution of these images.

What is the best method that can be used to create different combinations of sum of these images, using different percentage for each image.

for example:

```
Comb1 = 0.3*A + 0.5*B + 0.2*C
Comb2 = 0.25*A + 0.4*B + 0.35*C
Comb3 = 0.3*A + 0.7*B  (combine A and B only)
Comb4 = 0.6*B + 0.4*C  (combine B and C only)
```

In general:

```
CombN = x*A + y*B + z*C
```

or

```
CombN = x*A + y*B
```

or

```
CombN = x*B + y*C

.
.
. 

where x+y+z = 1
```

Is it possible to use Taylor series to create these combinations? And how to do this?

Comment: What is your goal? `CombN = x*A + y*B + z*C ` allows to create any possible linear combination, but why do you need them?

Comment: @MBo,  I want to use these combination to create a training data set. A, B, and c are just an example I have more than 3. If I have unknown combinations of images, CombX, I can find it, by measuring a correlation between CombX and all training data set.

Comment: what do you mean with "best method"? What is "best"?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to create combinations with Max grades for every coefficient, and sum of these coefficients should be equal to 1:

```
 for x = 0 to Max
    for y = 0 to Max - x
       z = Max - x - y
       MakeCombination(x/Max, y/Max, z/Max)
```